# How to process (find mean and standard deviation) replicated data using pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to Python and lately I have been trying to find the mean and standard deviation of data using pandas and NumPy.

I have columns representing three replicates (for two clones i.e. C1 and C2) that I need to average and then plot those averages with the standard deviations as the error bars.

Below is a data frame with 'time' in the first column and the replicates ([2:4, 5:7]).

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long` to transform the table and then plot with `seaborn`?

Comment: [df.std()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), [df.mean()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I need averages of (C1_1, C1_2, C1_3 and C2_1, C2_2, C2_3) as two new columns with its standard deviations as well. Can I use something like this: df.groupby("col_to_group_by").agg([func_1, func_2, func_3]) ?? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Load your data as pandas dataframe ( your question gives no clue from where to load the data - so i cannt help you fruther with this step)

With the pandas function `YOUR_DATAFRAME.describe()` you can print the std and the mean of each column.

(Might add `.T` to change the orientaion of your dataframe )

Comment: I want to calculate the average of the three columns (c1_1, c1_2, c1_3) as C1_ave and the last three columns (c2_1, c2_2, c2_3) as C2_ave.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Something like in the attached picture